# Complex numbers true or false

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Are there any complex numbers  "z" that satisfy this equation?  $$z=-\bar z?$$

Comment: Set $z=a+bi$ and check for yourself.

Comment: I don't know how...could you explain how I check?

Answer (score 5):

Write $z=x+iy$. Then your equation is

$$x+iy=-(x-iy)=-x+iy \Rightarrow x=-x, y=y \,.$$

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!

Comment: In other words all such $z$ are purely imaginary numbers.